# How to create a horizontal list with a separator only if it is not the last character of the line?

Tags: lists

The goal is to have a list whose members are displayed horizontally with a separator that is shown only if it is not the end of the string.

The code below produce something similar to what I want but in a very bad way. In particular, the last solution (that is the one with the closest result to the one I want) mess a bit with the spaces in the case of a list of sentences instead of words.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\begin{document}
% 1. List of items with a bullet separator
Lorem 
\textperiodcentered{} ipsum 
\textperiodcentered{} dolor 
\textperiodcentered{} sit 
\textperiodcentered{} amet 
\textperiodcentered{} consectetur 
\textperiodcentered{} adipiscing 
\textperiodcentered{} elit 
\textperiodcentered{} sed 
\textperiodcentered{} do 
\textperiodcentered{} eiusmod 
\textperiodcentered{} tempor 
\textperiodcentered{} incididunt 
\textperiodcentered{} ut 
\textperiodcentered{} labore 
\textperiodcentered{} et 
\textperiodcentered{} dolore 
\textperiodcentered{} magna 
\textperiodcentered{} aliqua.

% 2. The same as before but with forced line-breaks without separator
Lorem 
\textperiodcentered{} ipsum 
\textperiodcentered{} dolor 
\textperiodcentered{} sit 
\textperiodcentered{} amet 
\textperiodcentered{} consectetur 
\textperiodcentered{} adipiscing 
\textperiodcentered{} elit\\
sed 
\textperiodcentered{} do 
\textperiodcentered{} eiusmod 
\textperiodcentered{} tempor 
\textperiodcentered{} incididunt 
\textperiodcentered{} ut 
\textperiodcentered{} labore 
\textperiodcentered{} et 
\textperiodcentered{} dolore \\
magna 
\textperiodcentered{} aliqua.

% 3. Introducing \hfill to justify the list.
Lorem 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill ipsum 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill dolor 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill sit 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill amet 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill consectetur 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill adipiscing 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill elit\\
sed 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill do 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill eiusmod 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill tempor 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill incididunt 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill ut 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill labore 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill et 
\hfill \textperiodcentered{} \hfill dolore \\
magna 
\textperiodcentered{} aliqua.
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Typographically, the first list looks better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a discretionary (the same mechanism used for hyphens at ends of lines)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\newcommand\zzz{%
\ifhmode\unskip\fi
\leavevmode
\nobreak\hspace{.3em plus 5em}%
\discretionary{}{}{\textperiodcentered}\nobreak
\hspace{.3em plus 5em}%
}

\begin{document}
% 1. List of items with a bullet separator
Lorem 
\zzz ipsum 
\zzz dolor 
\zzz sit 
\zzz amet 
\zzz consectetur 
\zzz adipiscing 
\zzz elit 
\zzz sed 
\zzz do 
\zzz eiusmod 
\zzz tempor 
\zzz incididunt 
\zzz ut 
\zzz labore 
\zzz et 
\zzz dolore 
\zzz magna 
\zzz aliqua.


\end{document}
```

Comment: I really liked this solution. It does however possibly leave the first ```\hspace``` stranded before the newline, making the paragraph stand out from surrounding text. Would there be a way of preventing this? The rule of not putting glue inside a discretionary seems to preclude this.

Comment: @typewriter better to ask a new question than comment on an old one. As far as I can see this has `\nobreak`  before both hspace, so it should not break there.